# Language of the graph of an affine function

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, integers

Write $\bar n$ for the decimal expansion of $n$ (with no leading `0`). Let `:` be a symbol distinct from any digit. Let $a$ and $b$ be integers, with $a > 0$. Consider the language of solutions of the Diophantine equation $y=ax+b$:

$$L = \{ \bar{x} \mathtt: \bar{y} \mid y = a\,x + b \}$$

Is $L$ regular? context-free?

(Contrast with [Language of the values of an affine function](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/640/language-of-the-multiples-of-an-integer))

<sub>(Follows on [How can solutions of a Diophantine equation be expressed as a language?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/618/how-can-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation-be-expressed-as-a-language))</sub>

<sub>I think this would make a good homework question, so answers that start with a hint or two and explain not just how to solve the question but also how to decide what techniques to use would be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: Wouldn't $\{ \bar{x} \mathtt: \bar{y}^{-1} \mid y = a\,x + b \}$ be much more interesting? Or do you think this should be a different question?

Comment: @jmad Definitely a different question, since the answer is different.

Comment: Are you asking "Is $L$ regular/cf *for all* $a,b$?" or "For which $a,b$ is $L$ regular/cf?"? Also, note that the answer to the question changes if we encode number with a unary alphabet.

Comment: @Raphael Take your pick, since the answer doesn't depend on the values of $a$ and $b$. I did specify decimal; any base would do, whereas a unary notation does change the answer.

Comment: @Gilles: The answer might not depend on the interpretation, but a proof might. For instance, my (hidden) one solves the first, but not the second interpretation.

Comment: @jmad: By $\bar{y}^{-1}$ you mean the reverse? Would expect $\bar{y}^R$; no idea what is more canonical.

Comment: @Raphael: yes I meant that. $w^R$ is probably better because $w^{-1}w'$ could be a residual language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$53 \cdot 100000010000000000 + 4 = 5300000530000000004$.

Sketch:

> Assume $a$ has $n$ digits and $b$ has $m$ digits.
>
>  If $\overline{x}=10^k \underbrace{00\dots01}_{n}0^l\underbrace{00\dots0}_{m}$ for some $k,l$ then
>
>  $\overline{ax+b}=\overline{a}0^k \overline{a} 0^l \overline{b}$.
>
>  If $L$ was context-free, then
>  
>  $$L'=L \cap 10^{\ast}0^{n-1}10^{\ast}0^m \mathtt: (0+1+2+...+9)^{\ast} = \{10^{k+n-1}10^{l+m} \mathtt: \overline{a}0^k\overline{a}0^l\overline{b}:k,l \in \mathbb N\}$$
>  would be context-free as well.
>  
>  Given a PDA $M$ for $L'$ we could construct a PDA $N$ for $\{a^n b^m c^n d^m\}$ , a well-known non-context-free language. $N$ simulates $M$, but it is "feeding" different letters; it is a composition of $M$ with a transducer. Initially, $N$ behaves as if $M$ read $1$. Then, consecutive $a$'s are interpreted as $0$'s. Next, $N$ behaves as if $M$ read $0^{n-1}1$, and treats consecutive $b$'s as $0$'s, then as if it read $0^m \mathtt: \overline{a}$ etc.

Comment: That's clever. The hint alone wasn't enough; I'd seen that but hadn't realized you could subsequently do <spoiler> to get to a classical example.

Comment: Beautiful. I stand outclassed.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "Is $L$ regular?": You should reflexively check the [Pumping condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages); can a long solution $\bar{x}:\bar{y}$ be pumped?

> No, it can not. Assume a pumping constant $p$. Because $y = ax + b$ has arbitrarily large solutions ($a>0$ !), we can choose one solution $(x',y')$ with $|\bar{x'}| > p$. Then, $xy$ (from the Pumping Lemma) has to be a prefix of $\bar{x'}$. Pumping $y$ now increases $x'$ but $y'$ remains unchanged; we leave $L$.

As for "Is $L$ context-free" (assuming above question was answered negatively) it is wortwhile to consider special cases of $L$, as the question implicitly asks wether $\{L_{a,b}\} \subseteq \mathrm{CFL}$. Can you find a combination of $a,b$ that allows an easy proof?

> Indeed! $a=1$ and $b=0$ leads to $L = \{\bar{x}:\bar{x} \mid x \in \mathbb{N}\}$. We know that this language is not context-free by $\{ww \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ (the canonical example).

Comment: How does that work to pump harder, to show the language is not context-free?

Comment: Pumping in the context-free sense should destroy the solution, too, but I don't have a formal proof of that yet.

Comment: I'd gotten this far; doing the multiplication or the addition is where I get lost.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**: What happens when $a=1$ and $b=0$?

OK, we nailed it for a specific pair $a,b$. Now, does it will become any different for other $a,b$?

**Hint 2**: Go on with $b=0$ and arbitrary $a$

**Hint 3**: Try to think what happens if $a=0$ and $b$ is not. This can't happen in this question, but it should give you the idea how to cope with $a,b \ne 0$.

Comment: Hint 2.2 is where I'm stuck. What closure property can transform $\{\bar x:\bar x\}$ to handle the additions and multiplications?

Comment: I guess I meant looking at something like $L'=\{x:xy\}$ for any $y$. However now I'm not so sure anymore it is so easy to get via closure properties.

Comment: @Gilles It should be just easier to pump. Thanks for your comment! I'll edit the answer.